# Reminder Model using SignalR in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

**Overview:** I want to create a remainder for user input with alarm notification. I have a view Page with username and date to enter. If submission is successful, it should store in database. Using **signalR**, I want to trigger the reminder if client time(machine time) and user input time(server time) matches. It should give a popup window to show notification with user name and reminder time.

**Explanation:**

```
Homepage

Username: textbox

Reminder date and time: textbox

Save reminder: button
```

User clicks save reminder, and the time get saved in the database.
Show a popup with the username, when the current time corresponds with the reminder date and time using Signal R.

(To check the output, open the localhost url in two different browsers and see whether the popup is getting opened at the same time.)

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr), keep in mind that checking if the dates match will require some sort of periodic task (if you want to keep all in the same web application you can look at [HangFire](http://hangfire.io))

One simple approach will look like this:

**Hub**

Kepp in mid that if you have more than one server or working process you may have to store the mapping between the SignalR connection and the username somewhere else look [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

```
public class ReminderHub : Hub
{

    public Dictionary<string,string> _conn = new Dictionary<string,string>();


    public void Store(string username, DateTime date)
    {
        // Store into the database
        // ....
        // ...

        // Store the realation between the connection and the username
        _conn.Add(username,Context.ConnectionId);


    }

    public void Notify(string username)
    {
        // notify method is defined in the client (js)
        Clients.User(_conn[username]).notify(username);
    }
}
```

**Web Client**

Details like date formatting and others are details are omitted to keep the answer short

```
var hub = $.connection.reminderHub;
hub.client.notify = function (username) {
    alert(username)
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   // Wire up save reminder option.
   $('#save').click(function () {
        hub.server.Store($('#username').val(), $('#date').val());

   });
});
```

**Task**
For the periodic task you have multiple options, a HangFire task, a window service or event a simple console app running as a Schedule Task.

I will assume that is a Console app.

You will need the [.Net SignalR Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client), take a look to have the proper setup of the client.

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("**YOUR URL**);
await hubConnection.Start();
IHubProxy proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ReminderHub");

// QUERY THE DATABASE Check if there's any user to notify
for(var username in UsersToNotify){
    proxy.Invoke("Notify", username);

}
```

Keep in mind that there's a lot to me improved this code is just simple approach.

Comment: Is there any replacement for using Dictionary here?

Comment: Sure, actually you may have some sort of authentication already maybe take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections), you can map the using something like Redis or a Service State Server.

Comment: ok. I have another doubt. I need to show datetime control for user input. I know there is datetime input type in html 5. But datetime is not supported by my browser. So How can i display datetime control?

Comment: Hi, this question is not particularly related to the original one. There are plenty of alternatives out there you can go with [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), [KendoUI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index), [Wijmo](http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/PureJS/InputIntro/InputIntro/) or a lightweight solution like [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday).